# Mejorar código en cakephp

Tags: ajax, mvc, cakephp, model

Tengo la siguiente pregunta: como convertir este codigo de php basico a cakephp:

Controlador

```
public function politics_index($active_pill = null)
{
    $this->layout = 'politics';
    $user = $this->Auth->user();

    $doctor = $user['Doctor'];
    $doctorId = $user['Doctor']['id'];

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "bd", "user", "clave");

            // Check connection
            if($link === false){
                //echo("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
            }

            // Attempt update query execution
            $sql = "UPDATE doctors SET acepto='Si' WHERE id=$doctorId";
            if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
                echo "<div hidden>respuestaAceptoDoctorQueIngreso=Si</div>";
            } else {
                echo "<div hidden>respuestaAceptoDoctorQueIngreso=No</div>";
            }

            // Close connection
            mysqli_close($link);
        //mysqli_close($conexion);
    } 
    else {
        $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "bd", "user", "clave");

        mysql_select_db("interqui_web",$conexion);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM doctors where id=$doctorId";
        if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $acepto=$row['acepto'] ;
            if($acepto==="Si"){
                echo "<div hidden>respuestaAceptoDoctorQueIngreso=Si</div>";
            } else {
                echo "<div hidden>respuestaAceptoDoctorQueIngreso=No</div>";
            }
        }
        mysqli_close($link);
    }

}
```

Modelo

```
class Doctor extends AppModel {
  public $belongsTo = array('Doctitle');
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Education' =>
            array(
                'className' => 'Specialty',
                'joinTable' => 'doctor_education',
                'foreignKey' => 'doctor_id',
                'associationForeignKey' => 'specialty_id',
                'unique' => true,
            ), 
    );

    public $validate = array(
        'name' => array(
            'rule' => 'notBlank'
            ),
        'image' => array(
            'rule' => array(
              'isValidMimeType', 
               array('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif'),
               false
            ),
            'allowEmpty' => true,
            'message' => 'File is not an image',
        ), 
    );



    /* using the upload plugin */
     public $actsAs = array(
        'Upload.Upload' => array(
            'image' => array(
              'path' => '{ROOT}webroot{DS}img{DS}uploads{DS}',
                'thumbnailSizes' => array(
                    'thumb' => '150w'
                ),
              // uncoment next if "imagick not found"
              'thumbnailMethod' => 'php', 
            ),             
        )
    );

}

?>
```

Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("input[type=checkbox]").on( "click", function(){
    if( $('.input-check-borrado').is(':checked') ) {
        var parametros = {
            "doctorName" : $(".doctorTitle").text(),
            "loActivo" : "Si"
        };
        console.log($(".doctorTitle").text());
        $.ajax({
            data:  parametros,
            url:   '/politics/config',
            type:  'post',
            /*dataType: "json",*/
            beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#resultado").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
            },
            success:  function (response) {
                    if(response.indexOf("respuestaAceptoDoctorQueIngreso=Si")> -1){
                        $('input.input-check-borrado').attr("disabled", true);
                    }
                    else {
                        $("input.group1").removeAttr("disabled");
                    }
            }
        });
    }
});});
```

Si te detallaste en el ajax, tengo una linea documentada, es debido a que no se como retornar un simple si o un no por json encode, ps al recibirlo en el ajax el response estaba vacío, no se si sepas que me falto ps tenia el data type del js en 'json' y en el controlador string json_encode("si"); al ppio pensé que tenia que devolver c¡un array por lo cual devolví la variable $user que se que es un arreglo

Comment: Si, es que yo en el ejemplo que tengo uso el modal para conectarme con la BD, así: `$this->loadModel('Need');

                $this->Need->create();
                if ($this->Need->save($this->request->data)) {
                    $this->Need->save(array(
                        'date' => date("Y/m/d")
                    ));`

y ahí inserto datos como por ejemplo la fecha

Comment: Estoy teniendo un problema, como retorno un valor en el controlador? tenia un return pero no funcionaba.

Comment: En el response del ajax me recibe todo el código de la pagina.

Comment: Dale, ojala me sirva.

Comment: Hola! Ahora lo que necesitas es ponerlo en sintaxis de CakePHP y regresar el json en la respuesta de ajax verdad?

Comment: @KacosPro Así es, y la cosa es que al ponerlo en Cake no me funciona ps no me conecta con la tabla de la bd. y lo del json no me dio cuando lo intente, en el ajax puse `dataType: 'json'` y en el controller devolvia con el `echo json_encode($arreglo);` y en el  `console.log(response);` del ajax me mostraba vacio

Comment: Esto se convirtió en una nueva pregunta XD actualizaré mi respuesta pero la próxima considera abrir una pregunta nueva :)

Comment: @KacosPro si jejejeje si algo ps lo puedo hacer. En una hora que formule hace un rato una.

Comment: No, decía para la próxima jaja te ayudaré con esta aquí

Comment: @KacosPro A bueno, esta es la otra pregunta por si sabes como hacerlo https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/159813/crear-administrador-en-cakephp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder usar un modelo desde otro controlador puedes usar `$this->loadModel('Model')` y trabajar como lo haces normalmente.
También no necesitas llamar los métodos de mysql directamente, CakePHP lo hace por ti al llamar sus métodos, aparte que ya los sanitiza para evitar la inyección SQL.

[Aquí](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#findby) puedes ver más sobre la función mágica `findBy`, y [aquí](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savefield-string-fieldname-string-fieldvalue-validate-false) sobre actualizar un campo

También es importante revisar si la petición es de tipo JSON y de esta forma regresar un objeto JavaScript para poder manipularlo

En tu controlador el código quedaría así

```
public function politics_index($active_pill = null)
{
    // Si la petición es json regresamos json
    // puedes ver mas en: https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#JsonView
    if ($this->RequestHandler->ext == 'json') {
        $this->viewClass = 'ResponseJson';
    }

    $this->layout = 'politics';
    $user = $this->Auth->user();

    $doctor = $user['Doctor'];
    $doctorId = $user['Doctor']['id'];

    $this->loadModel('Doctor');
    $tempDoctor = $this->Doctor->findById($doctorId);

    if ($this->request->is('post') && !empty($tempDoctor)) {
        $this->Doctor->id = $doctorId;

        $this->Doctor->saveField('acepto', 'Si');
        $tempDoctor['Doctor']['acepto'] = 'Si';
    }

    if (!empty($tempDoctor)) {
        $this->set('acepto', $tempDoctor['Doctor']['acepto']);
    }
}
```

Para llamar al método del controlador directamente lo hacemos como normalmente se haría una petición, con la URL del controlador. Es importante pasarle `dataType: "json"` para que regrese un JSON y no el código de la página.

Tu petición ajax quedaría así, tu respuesta debe venir en `response.data.items`

```
$.ajax({
    data:  parametros,
    url:   '/politics/config',
    type:  'post',
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function () {
        $("#resultado").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
    },
    success:  function (response) {
        // Tu lógica a seguir de acuerdo a la respuesta obtenida
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: Te voy a montar dos códigos y dime que error tengo ve al final de la pregunta.

Comment: Edité mi pregunta, creo que ahora si debe hacer lo que buscas

Comment: Te voy a subir en una imagen el código que tengo, que ya lo hice pero use select y update al estilo de php basico, como dices, eso previene el sql inyección

Comment: la foto esta al final de la pregunta

Comment: Mejor edita tu pregunta con el código de las imagenes para que sea mas legible

Comment: Listo, ya lo hago

Comment: ya la edite y subí los códigos que tengo.

Comment: Actualice mi respuesta :)

Comment: Tengo solo dos preguntas, pero no son para este ejemplo especifico, en el ajax se envia parametros aqui ya sobra ps porque todo esta en $doctor, pero si yo quisiera enviar información como lo leería en php ? ps yo lo había intentado con $_post['variable1'];
la otra pregunta es con console.log(respose.data.items); ya me mostraria el arreglo?

Comment: Si tu ajax es de tipo `POST` lo harías así `$this->request->data('parametro')` o `$data = $this->request->data; $data['parametro']`. Y `console.log(respose.data.items)` te muestra todo lo que devuelves en el `$this->set()`. Si quieres devolver todo el doctor lo harías así: `$this->set('doctor', $tempDoctor);` y en js `console.log(respose.data.items.doctor)`

Comment: Te dare el chulo, ya en un rato voy a hacer la prueba y si algo te menciono. Si sabes hacer lo de administrador ?

Comment: Marcala solo si solucionó tu problema, ahora veo lo del administrador