# Crear administrador en cakephp

Tags: mvc, cakephp, router, administración-de-software

Muy buenos días tengo un problema cree el usuario administrador pero la pagina no me funciona, aquí están los códigos:

Estos códigos estan copiados del book de cake 2.x

Si hago esto entra bien:

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
    class AppController extends Controller {
          public $components = array(
            'Session' ,
             'Auth' => array(
                 'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'),
                 'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')
             )
          );

          public function beforeFilter() {
              $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');
          }
    }
```

[image: Index]
La cosa es que me la pide desde la pagina principal y eso no es lo que quiero, si mi pagina principal es [Index](http://www.miweb.com), quiero que me lo pida en [Idex/Admin](http://www.miweb.com/admin)

Estos son los codigos que tengo
UsersController

```
<?php

// app/Controller/UsersController.php

App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class UsersController extends AppController {

    // app/Controller/UsersController.php

    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        // Allow users to register and logout.
        $this->Auth->autoRedirect = false;
    }

    public function login() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
            }
        }
    }

    public function logout() {
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->User->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('users', $this->paginate());
    }

    public function view($id = null) {
        $this->User->id = $id;
        if (!$this->User->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }
        $this->set('user', $this->User->findById($id));
    }

    public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->User->create();
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(
                    __('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.')
            );
        }
    }

    public function edit($id = null) {
        $this->User->id = $id;
        if (!$this->User->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }
        if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(
                    __('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.')
            );
        } else {
            $this->request->data = $this->User->findById($id);
            unset($this->request->data['User']['password']);
        }
    }

    public function delete($id = null) {
        // Prior to 2.5 use
        // $this->request->onlyAllow('post');

        $this->request->allowMethod('post');

        $this->User->id = $id;
        if (!$this->User->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }
        if ($this->User->delete()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('User deleted'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('User was not deleted'));
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }

}
```

User modelo

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class User extends AppModel {
    public $validate = array(
        'id' => array(
            'rule' => 'notBlank'
        ),
        'user' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => 'notBlank',
                'message' => 'A username is required'
            )
        ),
        'key' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => 'notBlank',
                'message' => 'A password is required'
            )
        ),
        'rol' => array(
            'valid' => array(
                'rule' => array('inList', array('admin', 'author')),
                'message' => 'Please enter a valid role',
                'allowEmpty' => false
            )
        ),
        'created' => array(
            'rule' => 'notBlank'
        )
    );
}
```

Login vista

```
//app/View/Users/login.ctp

<div class="users form">
<?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            <?php echo __('Please enter your username and password'); ?>
        </legend>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('username');
        echo $this->Form->input('password');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Login')); ?>
</div>
```

Incluso enrute para ver si con eso me hacia lo que mencione en www.../admin pero eso no hace es anda.

```
Router::connect('/admin', array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'display', 'Users/login'));
```

así funciona, pero si documento AppController quedando así:

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
class AppController extends Controller {
//      public $components = array(
//        'Session' ,
//         'Auth' => array(
//             'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'),
//             'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')
//         )
//      );
//      
//      public function beforeFilter() {
//          $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');
//      }
}
```

Ps sale esto:

[image: Index]

Ps esto es el index como debe ser, ahora si voy a www.../admin
[image: Index/Admin]
Ahora siven en admin saca eso, y a pesar de que saca errores me saca el layout default y lo quiero cambiar o que al menos no me muestre el menu(rayas en la parte derecha) ps ese menu es solo para clientes nuevos

Comment: No hice unos cambios y ya me saca otro error. ya te muestro, actualizare la pregunta.

Comment: @KacosPro ya la edite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes lograr lo que deseas con los prefijos.

Para poder tener una sección de administrador tienes que declarar primero un prefijo en tu archivo `app/Config/core.php` buscamos/creamos esta línea con tus prefijos como segundo parámetro

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));
```

De esta forma podemos declarar la funcion `prefijo_accion()` en cualquier controlador, por ejemplo si queremos tener la ruta http://example.com/admin/users/login declaramos la función `admin_login` de esta forma

UsersController.php

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class UsersController extends AppController {
    // Resto del código ...
    public function admin_login () {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
            }
        }
    }
    // Resto del código ...
}
```

Para la vista debemos crear el archivo con el prefijo admin, por ejemplo *admin_accion.ctp*, para este caso creamos el archivo `app/View/Users/admin_login.ctp`,

Y si necesitas declarar un layout diferente para la vista de administrador puedes crear un archivo en la carpeta Layouts, digamos `app/View/Layouts/admin.ctp`, y en tu AppController.php en tu función `beforeFilter` decirle que si es admin ocupe el layout que tu deseas, de esta forma:

```
<?php
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
class AppController extends Controller {
    // Resto del código ...
    public function beforeFilter() {
        // Resto del código ...
        if (!empty($this->request->params['prefix'])  && $this->request->params['prefix'] == 'admin') {
            $this->layout = 'admin';
        }
        // Resto del código ...
    }
    // Resto del código ...
}
```

La lógica de la autenticación y autorización es la misma, solo la pondrías dentro de las funciones con el prefijo admin `admin_función`.

Si quieres declarar una ruta específica para tu prefijo tienes que pasarle la opción en el parametro de la ruta, por ejemplo si queremos que el login sea en http://example.com/admin/login, tienes que hacerlo de la siguiente forma en tu archivo `routes.php`

```
Router::connect('/admin/login', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => true));
```

Comment: Voy a probar a ver si da, entonces agrego eso al controller, al rote y al core, el resto queda como esta? y el resto de las funciones de controller igual

Comment: creo que ya dio pero tengo unos códigos que no entiendo. del admin_login

Comment: Que hace esta linea: `return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());`?

Comment: Esa linea redirecciona a la URL que declaraste en `$this->Auth->loginRedirect`

Comment: Es decir la de app controller?

Comment: Correcto, puedes pasarle la URL que quieras, la ventaja de utilizar eso es que si venias de otro lado te redirecciona a donde estabas

Comment: me saca el sgt error al darle click :Fatal error: Call to a member function login() on null in /home2/estampil/public_html/Desarrollo/app/Controller/UsersController.php on line 32

Comment: Quitaste el Auth de tu variable $components en el AppController?

Comment: si mi error, ahora tengo un problema inserte en la BD, lo siguiente user: admin key: admin, e ingreso en la pagina esos datos y no hace nada, vuelve a la misma pagina. 
`return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());`supongo que aqui redirige pero esta redirigiendo a la misma pagina.

Comment: Esto esta en en appController : `'Session' ,
         'Auth' => array(
             'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'),`o deberia crear una pregunta nueva ?

Comment: Creo que si porque no me queda muy claro la pregunta jaja

Comment: Y para agilizar las preguntas/respuestas, enfocate en un solo problema por pregunta y marcala como resuelta solo si solucionó el problema :D